# How can I make click over a SVG element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, svg, web-scraping

I'm newbie with web scraping and using selenium I would like to make click over a SVG element to get access to the information showed by a modal window.

Making click over a point or cross in the basketball court of this webpage: https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart You will get a modal window with information like you can see in the next picture:

[image]

I have made this development which works find because find the "svg" element printing the values of his attributes "x" and "y":

```
b = self.driver
b.set_window_size(300, 300)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
    print("\n")
```

You can see exit of the code here:

```
x: 40.5 - y: 99.5
x: 151.5 - y: 211.5
x: 34.5 - y: 125.5
x: 35.5 - y: 121.5
x: 157.5 - y: 204.5
x: 59.5 - y: 122.5
x: 32 - y: 142
x: 40 - y: 121
x: 27.5 - y: 117.5
x: 164 - y: 124


x: 80.5 - y: 7.5
x: 49.5 - y: 111.5
x: 135.5 - y: 42.5
x: 34.5 - y: 67.5
x: 27.5 - y: 117.5
x: 138 - y: 54
x: 22 - y: 140
x: 119.5 - y: 32.5
x: 135.5 - y: 42.5
x: 154.5 - y: 186.5
x: 37.5 - y: 106.5
x: 39 - y: 117
x: 31 - y: 114
x: 40.5 - y: 117.5
x: 22 - y: 5
x: 46.5 - y: 4.5


x: 20 - y: 125
x: 148.5 - y: 197.5
x: 71.5 - y: 169.5
x: 118 - y: 230
x: 30.5 - y: 263.5
x: 25 - y: 124
x: 135.5 - y: 213.5
x: 82.5 - y: 128.5
x: 40 - y: 119
x: 158.5 - y: 131.5
x: 50.5 - y: 174.5


x: 166.5 - y: 82.5
x: 26 - y: 149
x: 36 - y: 133
x: 114.5 - y: 239.5
x: 48 - y: 222
x: 127.5 - y: 226.5
x: 23 - y: 132
x: 110.5 - y: 107.5
x: 114 - y: 138
x: 15 - y: 260
x: 137.5 - y: 131.5
x: 34 - y: 118
x: 75 - y: 65
x: 54.5 - y: 167.5
x: 30.5 - y: 127.5
```

But, If I try to make click over "svg" component adding this code:

```
        point = item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')
        point.click()
```

Finally, my code will be:

```
b = self.driver
b.set_window_size(300, 300)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
        point = item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')
        point.click()
    print("\n")
```

I've got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <svg class="shot-miss icon icon-miss clickable" x="40.5" y="99.5" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 30 30" title="">...</svg> is not clickable at point (44, 165). Other element would receive the click: <p class="cc_message">...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 5.4.0-88-generic x86_64)
```

How is that possible? What am I doing wrong? How can I get the content of the modal window?

**Edit I (solution provided by @Prophet):**

Now, my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

b = self.driver
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 20)
b.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cc_btn_accept_all"))).click()
b.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
        point = item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')
        point.click()
    print("\n")
```

And I've got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <svg class="shot-miss icon icon-miss clickable" x="151.5" y="211.5" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 30 30" title="">...</svg> is not clickable at point (805, 312). Other element would receive the click: <th class="player"></th>
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 5.4.0-88-generic x86_64)
```

**Edit II (solution provided by @cruisepandey:**

I have edited my code and now I've got this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


b = self.driver
    b.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
            b.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
    WebDriverWait(b, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']"))).click()
    for quarter in periods:
        shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
        for item in shots:
            print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
            point = item.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']")
            point.click()
        print("\n")
```

But, It doesn't work :( I've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/test/test_shot_chart_get_data.py", line 27, in test_something
    WebDriverWait(b, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']"))).click()
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/venv/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

**Edit III:**

I have tried to access to the "svg" tag through his absoloute XPath route. Using the tools for developers of Firefox or Chrome, we can get this absolute Xpath. In my case, I have got the XPath of the element in blue:

[image]

This is the route:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[1]/g/g[1]/g/g[1]/svg
```

If I try to acces to this route in my code I've got an error

```
b = self.driver
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 20)
b.set_window_size(300, 300)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
        periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
#WebDriverWait(b, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']"))).click()
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
        point = b.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[1]/g/g[1]/g/g[1]/svg")
        point.click()
    print("\n")
```

The error that I've got is this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[1]/g/g[1]/g/g[1]/svg"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 5.4.0-88-generic x86_64)
```

What am I doing wrong? What happend?

**Edit IV:**

I have modified in my code the string who gives me access to the svg but it doesn't work.

```
b = self.driver
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 20)
b.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
        periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
#WebDriverWait(b, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']"))).click()
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
        point = b.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='shot-chart_canvas']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='svg']")
        point.click()
    print("\n")
self.assertEqual(True, True, "Error!!!")
```

And the error that I get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <svg class="shot-miss icon icon-miss clickable" x="40.5" y="99.5" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 30 30" title="">...</svg> is not clickable at point (687, 917). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cc_banner cc_container cc_container--open">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609551 (5d576e9a44fe4c5b6a07e568f1ebc753f1214634),platform=Linux 5.4.0-88-generic x86_64)
```

Sorry, but I don't understand what happend :(((

Edit V:

I have to retrive the information of all the crosses and points. I've got two teams and inside this tag we've got an array of periods and inside of each period we've got all the shoots and of each shot-item I need to retrieve the information. So, how can I make an Xpath loop to retrieve the information of each shoot?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g tag` is under `svg tag`. so for locating `g.team-A`

Please use the below xpath :

```
//*[name()='g' and @class='team-A']
```

this is an xpath expression.

so the possible fix for this :

```
point = item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')
point.click()
```

to use this :

```
point = item.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']")
point.click()
```

What I would suggest here is to have a explicit wait defined and then you can try to click on it.

**Code-trial :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']"))).click()
```

for this explicit wait, you'd have to import these as well :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.shot-chart_canvas")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @class='chart']//*[name()='g']//descendant::*[name()='g' and @class='shot-item']"))).click()
a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.player-profile"))).get_attribute('innerText')
print(a)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**output :**

```
Q1 09:520 0
Alexandra Stolyar
2pt jump shot missed
View Player Profile
    FG  2Pts    3Pts    FT  Pts
In this game    
2/6
33.33%
    
1/4
25%
    
1/2
50%
    
3/3
100%
    8
```

**Update 2 :**

```
driver.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.shot-chart_canvas")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
all_points  = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @class='chart']//*[name()='g']//descendant::*[name()='g' and @class='shot-item']")))
print(len(all_points))
for point in all_points:
    point.click()
    a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.player-profile"))).get_attribute('innerText')
    print(a)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.icon--close"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Imports :**

```
119
Q1 09:520 0
Alexandra Stolyar
2pt jump shot missed
View Player Profile
    FG  2Pts    3Pts    FT  Pts
In this game    
2/6
33.33%
    
1/4
25%
    
1/2
50%
    
3/3
100%
    8
Q1 09:350 0
Karina Nizamova
3pt jump shot missed
View Player Profile
    FG  2Pts    3Pts    FT  Pts
In this game    
1/7
14.29%
    
1/3
33.33%
    
0/4
0%
    
2/3
66.67%
    4
```

Comment: @cruisepandy Thanks a lot for your appreciated help!!! But it doesn't work to me. Maybe I'm making something wrong. I don't know it. I have edit and exposed the error in my original post . You can find in **Edit II**

Comment: Where is `Edit II` ?

Comment: It's my code after your recommendations and the result that I've got. It doesn't work to me  :( I've got an error in: WebDriverWait(b, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']"))).click()

Comment: Once you are on page what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: Once I'm on the page I want to get the content that you get when you make click over a point or a cross. The content if what I have marked with a red square in the pic of my original post. If you visit the web page, make click over a cross or point in the basketball court. You will see that modal window. If you inspect that modal window with Firefox or Chrome you get the content in your console. I need that content.

Comment: @JoséCarlos : Please see above, I can get the text from first element, you can use find_elements to retrieve a list of web elements like that and proceed further.

Comment: OMG!!! It works!!! But now, I need to do this for all the points are crosses which are inside    <g class = "team-A"> and <g class = "team-B"> How can I do that to access to all of them?

Comment: I have updated my original post with **Edit V** @cruisepandey

Comment: @JoséCarlos :  This is actually a very good question, and unfortunately I do not know the proper answer. The thing is cross and point in red color are overlapped. Not all but few. When Selenium try to interact with the element which is underneath then it is not able to see the element causing element interact exception. Please see updated 2 section, it ideally would have worked if all the red mark point or cross signs are not overlapped to each other.

Comment: Hi @cruisepay You're complitely right!!! There are 119 shoots (between red and green points and cross) and I can process 91 of them. That's much better than nothing. Your development is perfect. Thank you very much for your appreciated help!!! You have help me a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The elements you are trying to click on are initially out of the visible screen. Also there is a "accept cookies" banner on the bottom.
You need to close the cookies banner and scroll the page up in order to make your code working.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
b = self.driver
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 20)
b.set_window_size(300, 300)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cc_btn_accept_all"))).click()

b.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
        point = item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')
        point.click()
    print("\n")
```

I would also recommend to use a normal window size, as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
b = self.driver
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 20)
b.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
b.get("https://www.fiba.basketball/euroleaguewomen/21-22/game/1310/MBA-Moscow-ZVVZ-USK-Praha#tab=shot_chart")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.cc_btn_accept_all"))).click()

b.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

periods = b.find_element_by_css_selector('g.team-A').find_element_by_css_selector('g.period-list').find_elements_by_css_selector("g.period-item")
for quarter in periods:
    shots = quarter.find_element_by_css_selector("g.shot-list").find_elements_by_css_selector("g.shot-item")
    for item in shots:
        print(f"x: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('x')} - y: {item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg').get_attribute('y')}")
        point = item.find_element_by_tag_name('svg')
        point.click()
    print("\n")
```

**UPD**
Svg, rect,g etc are special tag names.
`/svg` or `/g` Xpath will not work. You will need to use `/*[name()='svg']` or `/*[name()='g']` respectively.
Also, the absolute paths are strongly NOT recommended. You need to use better locators.
For example instead of

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[1]/g/g[1]/g/g[1]/svg
```

This will work better:

```
//div[@class='shot-chart_canvas']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='svg']
```

So instead of

```
point = b.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[1]/g/g[1]/g/g[1]/svg")
point.click()
```

Try this:

```
point = b.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='shot-chart_canvas']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='svg']")
point.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your appreciated help!!! But, it doesn't work to me :( I've got an error. I haved edited my original post with **Edit I** with the error

Comment: I can't find `<th class="player"></th>` on that page..

Comment: I don't know why returns that tag when that tag doesn't exists in the web page. :(

Comment: Thanks again for your appreciated help!!! But ... It doesn't work to me :((( I have updated my post in **Edit IV**